# Django: How to override default error message?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to customize `This field is required` error message but it doesn't work as expected.

First I tried to create custom validator.

`validators.py`

```
def required_field(input):
    if input is None or input == '':
        raise ValidationError("Custom error message")
```

and `models.py`

```
a_field = models.TextField(validators=[required_field])
```

However, the validator doesn't work and the default error message `This field is required.` shows up.

Second, I override the `clean` method

`models.py`

```
def clean(self):
    if not self.a_field:
        raise ValidationError({'a_field': 'Custom Error Message'})
```

The error message shows up but it is followed by default error message.
How can I override it directly?

I'm using `crispy_form` btw.

`html`

```
{{ form|crispy }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in the init method of the form

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
        model = MyModel

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['a_field '].error_messages = {'required': 'Custom Error Message'}
```